# Facebook Graph API Can't read public photo comments

Tags: facebook, api, graph

I'm trying to read all comments from some FB public post (w/ photo). I found some docs about FB Graph API and build the folowing request. But it fails.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=1542065625839944&version=v2.11

But I get this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1542065625839944' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "HQFdeKx0lqh"
  }
}
```

I also tried with user id 100001095643511_1542065625839944

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=100001095643511_1542065625839944%2Fphotos&version=v2.11

What am I doing wrong? Or is there other easy way to get comments?

Comment: `100001095643511` is a user profile, so you need their explicit permission to read their photos first (`user_photos`, maybe `user_posts` as well.)

Comment: in addition to what CBroe wrote: just because it is public on a user profile does not mean you can get it with the api. you ALWAYS need to authorize the user in order to get any data of his profile.

Comment: Thank you guys. But I tried facebook explorer with my personal account auth_token (I'm friend of profile)  and also FB APP secret auth_token with no result.